# Python rearrange a list without changing the values and making every rearrangment different

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

I want to write a function that get two integers. The integers indicate how many strings of either of the two chars appears in a string.

```
For example:
my_func(x,y): x amount of 'u' and y amount of 'r'. 
my_func(2,3) is a string 'uurrr'
```

And the goal of the function is to write all the possible combinations of that string without changing the amount of x,y and every rearrangement is different:

```
Example:
my_func(1,1) will return: 'ru', 'ur'
my_func(1,2) will return: 'urr', 'rur', 'rru'
my_func(2,2) will return: 'uurr', 'ruru', 'rruu','urur', 'ruur', 'urru'
```

What I tried without covering all cases:

```
RIGHT = 'r'
UP = 'u'
def factorial(m):
    if m>1:
        return factorial(m-1)*m
    else: 
        return 1
        
def binom(n,k):
    return int(factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k)))

    
def up_and_right(n, k, lst):
    if n-k == 1 or n-k==-1 or  n-k == 0 or n==1 or k==1:
        num_of_ver = n+k
    else:
        num_of_ver = binom(n+k,2)
    first_way_to_target = RIGHT*n + UP*k
    lst.append(first_way_to_target)
    way_to_target = first_way_to_target
    for i in range(num_of_ver-1):
        for j in range(n+k-1,0,-1):
            if way_to_target[j]==UP and way_to_target[j-1]==RIGHT:
                way_to_target = list(way_to_target)
                way_to_target[j-1] = UP
                way_to_target[j] = RIGHT
                way_to_target = ''.join(way_to_target)
                lst.append(way_to_target)
                        
    return lst
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Also, please show what the actual problem with the code is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.permutations` to get all the rearrangements, make a `set` of them to eliminate duplicates (because e.g. swapping two `r`s around counts as a separate permutation but doesn't change anything), and then join them back into strings because `permutations` returns character tuples instead.

This demonstration at the REPL should give you enough to write your function:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [''.join(p) for p in set(itertools.permutations('u' * 2 + 'r' * 2))]
['uurr', 'ruur', 'ruru', 'rruu', 'urur', 'urru']
```

Comment: `permutations('uurr')` works just as well; no need to create the list first.